# How do I intercept sort function within a JS proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-proxy

I know how to intercept `get``set` and such within a proxy using the following code:

```
function get( target, prop, receiver ) {
  console.log("Intercepted get")
  return Reflect.get( target, prop, receiver );
}
var handler = {
  'get': get
};
var proxy = new Proxy( new Array(...[7, 1,2,3,4,5]), handler );
```

I'm unable to replicate this for sort. Adding:

```
function sort(target, prop) {
  console.log("Intercepted sort")
  return Reflect.sort(target);
}
var handler = {
  'get': get,
  'sort': sort
};
```

Doesn't work. I've also been unable to find documentation. How do I intercept the `sort` function?

Comment: The first snippet works just fine. `proxy.sort();` displays `Intercepted get` several times. There is no `sort` handler. The [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions) is on MDN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `get` to trap methods. `get` is called for each property and each method that is read. The name of the property or method is passed into `get` as second argument `prop`:

```js
function sort() {
  console.log("Intercepted sort")
  return this.sort();
}
function get( target, prop, receiver ) {
  if (prop === 'sort') {
    return sort.bind(target);
  }
  console.log("Intercepted get")
  return Reflect.get( target, prop, receiver );
}
var handler = {
  get
};
var proxy = new Proxy( new Array(...[7,1,2,3,4,5]), handler );
console.log(proxy.sort())
```

Comment: How do I capture the function passed to the sort? I can't see it in the receiver property.

Comment: @BlueGranny You don't capture the function call. You capture the function access. You have to return a function, that expects a callback function. In my code I return `sort.bind(target)`. In JavaScript methods are just basic functions with a specific `this` context (that's a little bit simplified). The proxy doesn't have access and can't modify the actual function call.