# How do I intercept sort function within a JS proxy with a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-proxy

My previous related question: [How do I intercept sort function within a JS proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552687/how-do-i-intercept-sort-function-within-a-js-proxy/69552828#69552828)

Given the proxy:

```
function sort(customSort) {
  /* Write logs */
  console.log("Intercepted sort")
  return this.sort(customSort);
}
function get( target, prop, receiver ) {
  if (prop === 'sort') {
    /* How to capture custom sort?*/
    return sort.bind(target);
  }
  console.log("Intercepted get")
  return Reflect.get( target, prop, receiver );
}
var handler = {
  get
};
var proxy = new Proxy( new Array(...[7,1,2,3,4,5]), handler );
```

But now I add a custom sort function:

```
console.log(proxy.sort((a,b) => .... /* e.g., a-b */))
```

I cannot understand how to capture the function as to pass it to the proxy sort function. I've tried capturing different arguments in the `get` function, but can't find the correct one.

Comment: Don't you just need `function sort()` -> `function sort(a, b)`? I'm not sure what the proxy has to do with this here.

Comment: The proxy I have implemented does some other work as well, that's why I need to proxy

Comment: You need it *to do what*? I cannot understand what your expectation is here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The sort function within the proxy does some other work as well, e.g., writes logs. I then need to apply the same sort that the user was trying to do. I.e., the user needs to be oblivious to the proxy.

Comment: That was definitely not at all apparent to me from the question. You asked how to intercept the `sort()`  (and you have) and how to pass arguments. Not how to do custom logic *on top of* a supplied sorting function. If you had example usage it would have been a lot clearer that you expect `arr.sort(mySort)` to actually do `arr.sort(otherSorty(mySort))`

Comment: I have edited the question, please let me know if that is better. Furthermore, if you have the answer please feel free to answer :)

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849907/how-to-sort-only-part-of-array-between-given-indexes/62851253#62851253

Comment: @NinaScholz It does help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was similar to: [How to sort only part of array? between given indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849907/how-to-sort-only-part-of-array-between-given-indexes/62851253#62851253)

I return a function that accesses `argument[0]`

```
function sort(customSort) {
  /* Write logs */
  console.log("Intercepted sort")
  return this.sort(customSort);
}
function get( target, prop, receiver ) {
  if (prop === 'sort') {
    /* How to capture custom sort?*/
     return function(customSort) => {
       return this.sort(customSort || ((a,b) => a-b) )
     }
  }
  console.log("Intercepted get")
  return Reflect.get( target, prop, receiver );
}
```